# gitlab-runner on kubernetes on raspberry pi - container "helper" not found

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to run gitlab-runner on my kubernetes cluster on raspberry pi.

The gitlab pipeline generates the following output:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.4.0 (857480b6) on hello-world-gitlab-runner-6548-tq4mr (123)
Using Kubernetes namespace: gitlab
Using Kubernetes executor with image arm32v7/node ...
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-123-project-456-concurrent-789 to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-123-project-456-concurrent-789 to be running, status is Pending
Waiting for pod gitlab/runner-123-project-456-concurrent-789 to be running, status is Pending
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("helper")
```

The gitlab-runner pod logs the following output:

```
+ cp /scripts/config.toml /etc/gitlab-runner/
+ /entrypoint register --non-interactive --executor kubernetes
Running in system-mode.                            

Registering runner... succeeded                     runner=xyz
Runner registered successfully. Feel free to start it, but if it's running already the config should be automatically reloaded! 
+ /entrypoint run --user=gitlab-runner --working-directory=/home/gitlab-runner
Starting multi-runner from /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml ...  builds=0
Running in system-mode.                            

Configuration loaded                                builds=0
Metrics server disabled                            
Checking for jobs... received                       job=63348569 repo_url=https://gitlab.com/mypublicaccount/helloworld-docker.git runner=123
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("helper")  job=456 project=789 runner=123
Checking for jobs... received                       job=456 repo_url=https://gitlab.com/mypublicaccount/helloworld-docker.git runner=789
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): unable to upgrade connection: container not found ("helper")  job=123 project=456 runner=789
```

Any idea to fix this?

Comment: Does your container image have `git` in it?

Comment: @ChaosAffe which image do you mean? The gitlab-runner image or the deployed image?

Comment: The problem is most likely in the values.yaml for the gitlab-runner helm chart.
Without the values.yaml we would be guessing.

Answer (score 6):

I managed to specify helper container version (my runner was configured with [helm chart](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html) and [values.yaml](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/kubernetes.html#additional-configuration)) - official image supports ARM

```
runners:
  helpers:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner-helper:arm-latest
```

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. if you are running your RPi in 64 bit mode, you can use the `arm64-latest` tag as well.

Answer (score 0):

I probably just had a similar problem, so far no solution, but it seems the gitlab-runner is trying to pull and run the wrong gitlab-runner-helper. this is another docker image pulled and in my case it got pulled in x86 flavor. It cannot run on RPI, which is arm. This might help a bit...